# Keep hashed password on update using NodeJs Mongo and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, put

I am trying to build an application using MEAN. On register, everything works fine, user will be introduced into database with the fields password and verify hashed. But on update, the password and verify won't be hashed anymore and they will be added into database as a plain text. How can I resolve this? (I don't have the frontend code yet, I used Postman to send the request)

This is what I have by now:

model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var schema = new Schema({
  firstname: { type: String, required: true },
  lastname: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  verify: { type: String, required: true },
});

schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    user.verify = hash;
    next();
  });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

controller.js

```
var router = express.Router();

// register user
router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
  addToDB(req, res);
});  

async function addToDB(req, res) {
  var user = new User({
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    verify: req.body.verify
  });

  try {
    doc = await user.save();
    return res.status(201).json(doc);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }
}

// update user
router.put('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in user update: ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
      return next(err);
    }
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Mongoose middleware to only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new) e.g.

```
schema.pre('save',  function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password along with our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            user.verify = hash
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Because `findByIdAndUpdate` is a wrapper around `findOneAndUpdate`, better to use save so that the pre save hook is invoked

```
var _ = require('lodash');

// update user
router.put('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    // fetch user
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        _.assign(post, req.body); // update user
        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.json(200, post);
        })
    });
});
```